# How can I reinstall Matplotlib in my Anaconda Navigator to use in my Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed Python and Jupyter through Anaconda. I tried to reinstall Matplotlib and, after this, probably this installation created some error when I try to import Matplotlib. Always when I try to import Matplotlib I have the error below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-a0d2faabd9e9> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I tried installing Matplotlib again through the Anaconda Navigator. I open it\ go to 'Environments'\ base(root)\ all.
Then, I select `Matplotlib`and click 'Apply'. It does the installation. But afterwards, Matplotlib is still giving the same error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a0d2faabd9e9> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I would expect to get the import done, and start working with Matplotlib to create plots, but I only get this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mapped your command line interpreter to python, open command prompt (Windows) or Terminal (Mac) and type:

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

This will automatically install matplotlib for you. You can search other packages on https://anaconda.org/ for future downloads.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. How do I map my command line interpreter to python (I use a Mac)?

Comment: Hi, It worked!! Thank you so much kmck! To open Anaconda Command, what I did was 1. Open Anaconda Navigator, 2. Click on Environments, 3. Click on little triangle just on the right of base(root), 4. Clicked on 'Open Terminal'.